# Is there a way to make one CSS2DObject appear on top of another CSS2DObject? Or make it appear on top of all objects in the scene?

Tags: three.js

I want to make one CSS2DObject be on top of another, or on top of all CSS2DObjects in the scene. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with all other renderers, you can override the default z-order by defining [Object3D.renderOrder](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.renderOrder). If you set the value to `Infinity`, the instance of `CSS2DObject` should be rendered on top of all others. Use this code:

```js
label.renderOrder = Infinity;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't phrase the question correctly. I want the CSS2DObject to always appear on top, even if it's behind another CSS2DObject. 

To achieve this with a regular mesh, we can set its material depthTest property to false, and then set the renderOrder to Infinity. 

But what do we do in case of CSS2DObject?

Comment: Using `renderOrder` should be actually sufficient. This setting will indirectly control the `z-index` CSS property which determines the z-order of HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Turns out I was using older version of Three.js with no support of renderOrder by CSS2DRenderer

Comment: Render order support was added with `r138`.